# Accidentally removed read permissions from folder. How do I get back in?

Tags: permissions, ls, chmod

I wished to have a given folder and file and all descendants, write permissions.

I wished that ALL files and folders could be recursively granted he following permissions: 777

So I tried:

```
chmod -r 777 ~/Folder/app/
```

I then got something like:

```
chmod: 777: No such file or directory
```

I then did go to `~/Folder/app/` and tried to do a `ls -la` to check on permissions.

I get:

```
.: Permission Denied
```

I then did:

```
sudo ls -la
```

and then I've seen that .. special folder has: 777 permissions, but not the others.

How can I revert this, without deleting the `~/Folder/app/` folder ?

I mean:
**How can we allow the ls to work again without typing sudo inside that folder ? And somehow fix the mess I made by using -r instead of -R ?**

Comment: To my understanding, for recursive action, you need either `--recursive` or `-R`. I just want to make sure that what you put in your question is the command you actually used (to avoid misunderstandings) :)

Comment: Yes, I've used -r instead of the CAPITAL -R so, I've used -r lowercase.

Comment: You almost certainly almost never want 777, by the way.

Comment: @MEM: That may be your whole problem.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg : I realize that. The problem is, I don't know how to revert this. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I noted in my comments, you need to either supply `--recursive` or `-R` (capital R) to `chmod` so it works recursively.

`-r` (lower case R) means *remove read permissions* (at least to my understanding). This operation would then be applied to the **next** parameter, which is `777`.

So your call would remove read permissions from a file named `777`. That file does not exist, thus, the error message

```
chmod: 777: No such file or directory
```

I'm not sure if `chmod` then aborted or if it tried to *remove read permissions* from the **next** parameter `~/Folder/app/`.
In the latter case, it would even **remove** read permissions from your folder, doing exactly the **opposite** of what you wanted in the first place :)

Now, to resolve this, just use the **correct** syntax:

```
chmod --recursive 777 ~/Folder/app/
```

That will add the read permissions back (and apply your 777 mode on all children of that folder). Please take note of [Dennis Williamson's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/432404/ls-permission-denied#comment497755_432404), you almost never want to set a mode of 777.